# Weird floating <li> result

Tags: html, css, wordpress

So I created a list element that sits side by side using the float: left css tag and the result is found here: http://www.johnkimwell.com/chance/press-center/television/

I am not sure as to why the next element is not aligned. I have checked my code and this is always the code that I use whenever I want to float list elements.

Appreciate any help and tips. Thank you,

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend used `float:left` instead of `display:inline-block`

like this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        ul li{
            display: inline-block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a height to the `cat-item` class should be enough to make it work:

```
.cat-item {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 15px !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
    height: 100px;
}
```